# add methods to org.w3c.dom.Node

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I tried adding a custom method to the Node class but ended up creating a new class that holds a node object in a variable.

so the question is. is it even possible?

I did this:

```
public class Trip implements org.w3c.dom.Node { 
    [...generated methods...] 
    public String myMethod(){
        return "";
    }
}
```

but I was getting lots of errors so I ended up doing this

```
public class Trip { 
    private Node mNode;
    public void Trip(Node tripNode){
            this.mNode = tripNode;
    }
    public String myMethod(){
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither of those are valid Java syntax.

Comment: To me it looks like you don't really know what you are trying to do there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

org.w3c.dom.Node is an interface, therefore your posted code won't work.

You don't want to start trying to implement your own DOM, so I suggest you think of a different approach. What is it you want to do?

You might be able to make use of get and [setUserData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#setUserData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.w3c.dom.UserDataHandler%29) to accomplish your goal.

Comment: well the lest bit of code works for me, but I was just wondering.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is add a method that will get the string value of the first child element with a specific tagname like this (xml file is full of trips) tripNode.getValueOf("destination);

Comment: should it actually say "implements org.w3c.dom.Node"?

Comment: Well, that's probably the wrong way to go, given most nodes won't be Trip nodes. Can't you use getElementsByTagName to get the Elements you want then just get the text node?

Comment: By the way, you've just understood the difference between composition and inheritance :)

Comment: yes I can but I was trying to shorten my code :D by putting that procedure in a method. instead of doing it seperatly for each element and also they don't have to be trip nodes, even if they're destination nodes I can still use it like this destinationNode.getValueOf("description");

Comment: I don't see why you can't still put it in a method e.g. String getElementValue(Element n) { return n.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()}

Comment: I could but I have 3 activities I'd have to put it in all 3 activities.