# Save to XML DefaultMutableTreeNode - org.w3c.dom.Node

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am writing a simple configuration helper program to hold variables-value combinations and have the ability to save and load to XML files.

The basic structure is built around the DefaultMutableTreeNode that I extended with a few methods. For example the '[get(String variable)](https://github.com/Kazagha/Conf/blob/XML/src/net/arcanesanctuary/Configuration/ConfNode.java#L29)' method recursively searches the children of the node to find the value of the specified variable.

> String user = conf.get("Username");

After investigating saving to XML using the [DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/index.html) I realized it uses a similar hierarchical node structure, rather than double handling I considered using the 'org.w3c.dom.Node' for everything.

As I can't extend the Node interface in the same way (only implement it), what class actually implements Node? I can see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) that IOMetadataNode, SOAPPart implement the Node interface and there are a heap of subinterfaces.

Is a certain amount of [double handling](https://github.com/Kazagha/Conf/blob/XML/src/net/arcanesanctuary/Configuration/XMLController.java#L63) fine?

Comment: I can see that related questions advise against this;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206918/add-methods-to-org-w3c-dom-node?rq=1

Comment: This may work well enough, if the variables are automatically mapped to the XML data locations; http://stackoverflow.com/a/22352511/3387644

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to do away with the double handling using [MOXy](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted)

Following the example about [JAXBCustomizations](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/JAXBCustomizations) I used the below syntax to match the XML elements with the variables in my class. So long as there are setter/getter methods with matching names (For example var needs getVar and setVar methods) it's trivial to save to and load from XML.

> @XmlRootElement
>
> @XmlType(propOrder={"var", "value", "childNodes"})

The children nodes are instances of the same class as the parent and they are correctly nested underneath the parent.